# Mate desktop weird red icons in top right corner, how to remove/fix?

Tags: 14.04, mate

I installed recently ubuntu-mate-desktop on 14.04 and I have those weird red icons in top right corner that do nothing and I don't know how to remove them. Anyone knows what that is?

[image]

Comment: I believe it could be the mate-applet-lockkeys. You could check by right clicking on it and look for the about box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed Ubuntu mate 18.04 on my odroid and had similar problem, I was able to remove the icons by right clicking the 3 dots to the left and click lock, right click the 3 dots again and click remove.